# How many times FR4 can be put under a reflow process?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, reflow

I have a board with several designs, one component did not arrive so half of the PCB cannot be fabricated. In order not to waste time I would like to manufacture the designs that can be done but I don't know if the FR4 or the layers could be affected.

The PCB is 1mm thick and has 4 layers.

Comment: I'd be less worried about the PCB itself than about the components you're planning to put through the heat cycle multiple times.

Comment: the specific boards I can manufacture can be removed after the reflow, son only the PCB itself would be under heat more than once.